# After offering a bounty, reputation didn't change on other accounts User Page

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, bounties, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation display bug… Again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148636/reputation-display-bug-again)

I've noticed that in case I start a bounty on one account (*Stack Overflow for example*), it does not being reflected on my other linked-accounts user page.

I mean if I currently logged in to my Super User account (or any other) and enter my profile page, the reputation which appears near my Stack Overflow account appears unchanged. Was it supposed to work that way?

Comment: the accounts page is cached & will take some time to update

Comment: The bounty is already active for more than 4 days. Could it that much time?

Comment: nah, it shouldn't take that much time. Retagged.

Comment: That's what I've assumed..

Comment: [This similar rep inconsistency](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3344/programmers-total-points-not-listed-properly-on-stackoverflow) persisted for 4 days, so this might still be caching related /cc @Sathya

Comment: I see. I'll wait few more days and update again if the situation will not change.. Thanks.

Comment: I've often noticed discrepancies between those views, and assumed it was caching-related. It's been so often, I assume there must be some significant time delay.